# pyorient doesn't connect to OrientDB on port 2424 from cross-domain

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I'm connecting to my orientDB from one instance on AWS to another instance:

```
client = pyorient.OrientDB("129.123.12.123", 2424)
client.db_open(
                    "MyDB",
                    "root",
                    "secret",
                    db_type=pyorient.DB_TYPE_GRAPH
                )
```

The db_open call just hangs without connecting or errors. I suspect it's because I'm connecting from another IP. Is there a way around this? I have 1 server that host all my code and dockers but my orientDB nodes, running in a distributed cluster, have different IP's.

Comment: Did you check your connection first? Try to open a OrientDB console from the same server and try connecting to 129.123.12.123

Comment: Yes, I did test it and connected without problems.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with pyorient 1.5.4. The OrientSerialization.CSV gets stuck in an infinite loop when connecting to OrientDB in distributed mode.

There is a development branch on pyorient that implements the missing binary serialiser.

Install it with:

```
pip install https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/tarball/develop#egg=pyorient
```

connect using:

```
client = pyorient.OrientDB("129.123.12.123", 2424, serialization_type=pyorient.OrientSerialization.Binary)
```

This works but is obviously not stable yet.

Comment: There is currently a bug in pyorient_native that's causing a memory leak in Python. The developer of pyorient_native is currently looking into the matter.